# How to import MdDialog and MdDialogRef with a seperate Material Module

Tags: angular, import, material-design, angular-material

I created a separate modules for my few Material requirements.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdIconModule,MdDialogModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdIconModule, MdDialogModule],
  exports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdIconModule, MdDialogModule],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

I am importing this to my app-module and then to one of my component where I need a dialog box.

```
import {MaterialModule} from '../../materialModule/material.module';
```

Now how do I get hold of `MdDialog` and `MdDialogRef`  ?

I have seen tutorials doing it like :

```
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
```

But I guess it defeats the whole purpose of a separate module if I have to import from `@angular/material`.

Am I wrong in believing so. How exactly I import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} using my (recommended by Angular) approach ?

Comment: Hello, did to find a solution to the problem

Comment: Unfortunately No..I end up using primeng library for this, where the dialog box works as expected.